# How to import multiple csv files at once

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, file-organization

I have 30 csv files of wind speed data on my computer- each file represents data at a different location.  I have written code to calculate the statistics I need to run for each site; however, I am currently pulling in each csv file individually to do so(see code below):

```
from google.colab import files
data_to_load = files.upload()

import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data_to_load['Downtown.csv']))
```

Is there a way to pull in all 30 csv files at once so each file is run through my statistical analysis code block and spits out an array with the file name and the statistic calculated?

Comment: I'm not sure if your code is dependent on using pandas but if not you could use csv and do something like ````for filename in data_to_load: with open filename as f: reader = csv.reader(f...)````

Comment: data_to_load has the program ask me to select a file from my computer.  I don't believe it allows me to select all the csv files within my project folder.  Do you know of any function that allows you to select an entire folder to upload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a loop

https://intellipaat.com/community/17913/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe

```
import glob

import pandas as pd

# get data file names

local_path = r'/my_files'

filenames = glob.glob(local_path + "/*.csv")

dfs = [pd.read_csv(filename)) for filename in filenames]


# if needed concatenate all data into one DataFrame

big_frame = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Also you can try put data online: github or google drive and read from there
https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-load-csv-files-into-colab-7c14fcbdcb92