# Loading number of text files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, text-files, loading

I have output files generated output files with the extension `output.txt0001, output.txt0002,......,output.txt0020` from an MPI code. Is there any shorter way to load each txt file and concatenate them into a single array?

I am currently using `numpy.loadtxt` for each file and loading them into single arrays using `np.concatenate`.

```
h1 = np.loadtxt(p1,skiprows=1)
h2 = np.loadtxt(p2,skiprows=1)
h3 = np.loadtxt(p3,skiprows=1)
h4 = np.loadtxt(p4,skiprows=1)

halo_c = np.concatenate((h1,h2,h3,h4),axis=0)
```

Here `p1`,`p2`,... are paths of each text files which are located in same directory. I would like to know if there are any faster ways to do this using pandas or some other modules.

Comment: Do you want to increase the speed or reduce the code length? Also it might help if you posted example content from a file.

Comment: In the above code I just have only 4 text files, so I manually loaded them with np.loadtxt. But if I use number of processor around 50 for MPI run, then I will have output files generated as output.txt001....,ouput.txt050. So I need to reduce the code length as I don't want to load all 50 txt files one by one using np.loadtxt.  Contents of the files are just 6 columns of numbers.

Comment: so iterate over file paths in a list comprehension `[np.loadtxt(p,skiprows=1) for p in paths]`

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361624/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, which is quicker than just reading each file and then concatenate them:

```
import numpy as np
import glob

file_list = glob.glob('output.txt*')
# This lists all th files that are output.txt as startname , e.g., output.txt001 and so on

# Sort the file list by numerical order
file_list.sort()

array_list = []

# Loop through each file and append its contents 
for file_name in file_list:
    array_list.append(np.loadtxt(file_name))

combined_array = np.concatenate(array_list)
```